# How to get the unique ID to the buttons added to HTML cell dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have crated a `table` and added a `button` to every 3rd column of the table dynamically. I want to generate unique IDs for the buttons created as I have various functions to be performed on different button click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    var rows_length = document.getElementById("table").rows.length;
    var cell_length = document.getElementById("table").rows[2].cells.length;
    for (var j = 3; j < cell_length; j += 3) {
      for (var i = 2; i < rows_length; i++) {
        var cellChar_length = document.getElementById("table").rows[i].cells.item(j - 2).innerHTML;
        if (cellChar_length.length > 0) {
          var id_index = 0;
          table.rows[i].cells.item(j).innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" onclick="callButton(this)">Go</button>';
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will never have more than one button per cell, you could consider using `i` and `j` in the id of the button so you have deterministic IDs you can use from any point of the code.

```
var btn = `<button id="btn-${i}-${j}" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" onclick="callButton(this)">Go</button>`;
```

Otherwise you could just initialize a counter `var c = 0;` at the beginning of your function and just have your id as `"btn-" + c++` so you increase the counter everytime and all buttons will have different IDs.